# Merge two Dataframes based on two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a two dataframes: `df1` and `df_out`. 
`df1` looks like this

```
   phone_number1  phone_number2
1    123             123
2    345              0
3    678             678
4    912             912
5    555             666
```

And `df_out`

```
    phone_number  address   name
1      123         add1     name1
2     777777       add2     name2
3      666         add3     name3
4      555         add4     name4
```

And want to make something like this

```
    phone_number  address   name    df1_phone_number1    df1_phone_number2
1      123         add1     name1        123                  123
2     777777       add2     name2        None                 None
3      666         add3     name3        None                 666
4      555         add4     name4        555                  None
```

I tried this code, but it wont save data that match `phone_number2`

```py
    mergedStuff3 = pd.concat([
            pd.merge(df1, df_out,  how='right', left_on=['phone_number1'], right_on = ['phone_number']),
            pd.merge(df1, df_out,  how='right', left_on=['phone_number2', 'phone_number1'], right_on = ['phone_number', 'phone_number'])

        ])
```

Comment: I would just first merge to df_out, df1['phone_number1'] and than merge df1['phone_number2']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with check membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
m1 = df_out['phone_number'].isin(df1['phone_number1'])
m2 = df_out['phone_number'].isin(df1['phone_number2'])
df_out['df1_phone_number1'] = df_out['phone_number'].where(m1)
df_out['df1_phone_number2'] = df_out['phone_number'].where(m2)
print (df_out)
   phone_number address   name  df1_phone_number1  df1_phone_number2
1           123    add1  name1              123.0              123.0
2        777777    add2  name2                NaN                NaN
3           666    add3  name3                NaN              666.0
4           555    add4  name4              555.0                NaN
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m1 = df_out['phone_number'].isin(df1['phone_number1'])
m2 = df_out['phone_number'].isin(df1['phone_number2'])
df_out['df1_phone_number1'] = np.where(m1, df_out['phone_number'], None)
df_out['df1_phone_number2'] = np.where(m2, df_out['phone_number'], None)
print (df_out)
   phone_number address   name df1_phone_number1 df1_phone_number2
1           123    add1  name1               123               123
2        777777    add2  name2              None              None
3           666    add3  name3              None               666
4           555    add4  name4               555              None
```

If there is more columns solution should be changed:

```
for c in df1.columns:
    m = df_out['phone_number'].isin(df1[c])
    df_out[f'df1_{c}'] = np.where(m, df_out['phone_number'], None)
```

Comment: @ansev - yop, but still faster like `melt` + `merge`+ `pivoting`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) before [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), then only need join with [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

> this will work for n columns of phone number in df1

```
df_out.join(df_out.merge(df1.melt(),
                         how = 'inner',
                         left_on ='phone_number',             
                         right_on = 'value')
                  .pivot_table(index = 'phone_number',
                               columns = 'variable',
                               values = 'value'),
            on = 'phone_number')
```

**Output**

```
   phone_number address   name  phone_number1  phone_number2
1           123    add1  name1          123.0          123.0
2        777777    add2  name2            NaN            NaN
3           666    add3  name3            NaN          666.0
4           555    add4  name4          555.0            NaN
```